# jQuery - add class and run function with that it

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my html code:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">Button</a>
  <a href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

I have created this jQuery:

```
$(".wrap a").on("click", function(){
  $(this).addClass("new-one");
  $(this).siblings("a").removeClass("new-one");
});
$(".new-one").on("click", function () {
  console.log("I was hit!");
});
```

Why the function mapped on .new-one does not work? How can I fix it?

Comment: you are binding onclick to `.new-one` where as your `HTML` does not contain the element with that class?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, you are wright,

Comment: i think the class is added on to the anchor elements on click sorry for that the html is okay  @wright

Comment: Simple answer is that class doesn't exist at the time the code is run

Answer (score 2):

You need to [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) event handler. Something like this.

```
$(".wrap").on("click", ".new-one", function () {
    console.log("I was hit!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is a great way to achieve your end goal.  as to why your code doesn't behave as expected,
In this example, the code:

```
$(".new-one").on("click", function () {
  console.log("I was hit!");
});
```

Is getting run only once, when the script is loaded.  When this code runs, there is no element on the page with ".new-class" on it, therefore no click event is attached.
Put a click event on the container element and delegate to only children with the .new-one class and it will work.